# perfcurve return one value - matlab

Tags: matlab, roc, angular2-changedetection

I used sam (spectral angle mapper) to change detection in hyperspectral image after that want to plot roc(Receiver operating characteristic) using `perfcurve` function but function return one value. why? could you help me?

`[Xpr,Ypr,Tpr,AUCpr] = perfcurve(hyperdata_gt,abs(result),'1'); plot(Xpr,Ypr);`

[image]

Comment: the image is what you have or your goal?

Comment: sorry, ı don't understand  hyperdata_gt : target , result : obtained result

Comment: what is wrong with the picture you posted?

Comment: ı want to see exponential graph. (every sample) this picture return to one sample. Thank you for your working. ı solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[X,Y] = perfcurve(labels,scores,posclass);
plot(X,Y);
```

`labels` are the true labels of the data, `scores` are the output scores from your classifier (before the threshold) and `posclass` is the positive class in your labels.

I used 'after the threshold'.